# Understanding the BRDF Equation

Tags: raytracing, pathtracing, brdf, physically-based, reflection

I am studying the BRDF equation. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_reflectance_distribution_function#Definition), the equation is as follows:

[image]

I have one main question:

- **Where does the $\cos{\theta_i}$ in the denominator come from?** 
  The denominator implies that $dE_i(\omega_i) = L_i(\omega_i)\cos{\theta_i}d\omega_i$. Now, the text below the equation states that $L$ measures the power received on a projected area. But this should mean $L_i$ itself includes a cosine factor already; then, why do we need a $\cos{\theta_i}$ when equating $dE_i(\omega_i)$ to $L_i(\omega_i)$? Isn't the cosine factor already included from $L_i(\omega_i)$?

I am also confused about Wikipedia's reasoning for why $f_r$ is defined in terms of two differentials rather than the undifferentiated quantities:

[image]

What does "irradiating light other than $d E_i(\omega_i)$, which are of no interest for $f_r(\omega_i, \omega_r)$, might illuminate the surface" mean? How does the amount of light considered change when using $d E_i(\omega_i)$ in place of $E_i(\omega_i)$? And how  exactly would this "unintentionally affect" $L_r$?

Comment: Wikipedia is rather informal. The ratio is a Radon-Nikodym derivative. The cosine is from Lambert's law, or from treating radiance as a differential form, so when integrated on a surface it pops out a cosine factor (think surface flux integrals from multivar calculus).